# JsonExtensionData attribute with default DotNetCore binder

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to pass JSON with some dynamic fields to a controller action method in DotNetCore 3.1 Web API project. The class I am using when sending the payload looks something like this:

```cs
public class MyDynamicJsonPayload
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public IDictionary<string, object> CustomProps { get; set; }
}
```

I can see that object serialized correctly with props added to the body of JSON. So I send it from one service to another:

```cs
using var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync($"/createpayload", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

On the receiving end, however, when using same class in the controller action:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> CreatePayload([FromBody] MyDynamicJsonPayload payload)
{
    var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

    return Ok(payload);
}
```

The object is parsed as something different where `customProps` is an actual field with JSON object containing my properties, plus instead of a simple value I get a JSON object {"valueKind":"string"} for string properties for example. I tried with both `Newtonsoft.Json` and `System.Text.Json.Serialization` nothing works as expected. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Json.NET and System.Text.Json use the same name for their extension data attribute `[JsonExtensionData]`.   If you have both installed I recommend using the fully qualified names [`[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonExtensionData]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonextensiondataattribute) and/or [`[Newtonsoft.Json.sonExtensionData]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonExtensionDataAttribute.htm).  You may be mixing up serializers and attributes from different libraries.

Comment: Is there any chance you are **deserializing** with `System.Text.Json` and **re-serializing** with Newtonsoft?  If so, that could explain the behavior you are seeing.  Because if I round-trip your JSON using just `System.Text.Json` then everything works fine, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/i85pwt.

Comment: Looking more closely, `var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload)` isn't even going to compile. Can you share a real [mcve]?  Are you really manually serializing your `MyDynamicJsonPayload` to JSON using Newtonsoft?  If so, why?  Why not just return `return Ok(payload)` without manually serializing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you dbc for pointing me in the right direction, the problem was Newtownsoft vs System.Text.Json serialization/deserialization. I could not change the serializer in the Startup class because the service had many other methods and I didn't want to break existing contracts. However, I managed to write a custom model binder that did the trick:

```
public class NewtonsoftModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        string body = string.Empty;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(body, bindingContext.ModelType);

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreatePayload([ModelBinder(typeof(NewtonsoftModelBinder))] MyDynamicJsonPayload payload)
{
// Process payload...
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all welcome to the StackOverflow.

You can try this solution;

Fist create a class like you did but without dictionary;

```
public class History
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string AssetName { get; set; }
}
```

After that please add this attribute to your controller class;

```
[Produces("application/json")]
```

Your method should be like this;

```
[Produces("application/json")]
public class ExampleController: Controller 
{
   [HttpGet]
   public Task<IEnumerable<History>> Get()
   {
       List<History> historyList = new List<History>()
       {
           new History()
           {
             ...
           },
           new History()
           {
             ...
           }
       }
     
       return historyList;
   }
}
```